# How to update and add information (all together) by the single JSP page (hibernate is used here)?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

Product table has 3 columns (id, name and status). Status field has two values: "Available" and "NA". Output of this table will show by dividing into 2 tables based on the product availability.

Please follow the link for details:
http://theproblemdomains789.blogspot.com/2013/11/sample-form.html

Using hibernate, I tried to solve this. The output is OK. But i want to give permission to update or edit or add new information through the form. The update is OK and data is successfully updated. but when I tried to add new entry through the form, I am unable to add that. My sample codes are like the followings:

Bean definition:

```
  public Product{
String histryId;
String name;
String status;

.....
 }
```

Action class definition:

```
List<Product> dataList;
String[] histryId;
String[] name;
String[] status;

// getter and setter
......

public String viewProduct() {
    ....
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String updateProduct() {
    ProductBusiness pb = new ProductBusiness();
    dataList = pb.updateProduct(name,histryId,status););
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

## Business layer:

```
public List<Product> updateProduct(String[] name, String[] histryId, String[] status) {

    ProductDAO historyDAO = new ProductDAO();

    for (int i = 0; i < historyId.length; i++) {
        if (historyId[i] > 0) {
        Product update = historyDAO.getEntryByID(Integer.toString(historyId[i]));
        update.setName(name);
        historyDAO.updateEntry(update);
    }

    else{                   
        if (name[i].length()>0  && (status[i] == "Available") ) {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.setName(name);
        historyDAO.updateEntry(p);                          
        }
    }
}
```

## DAO layer

```
public void updateEntry(Product p) {
    ...
    s.saveOrUpdate(p);
    ...
}
```

## Sample JSP code:

```
<s:iterator value="dataList">
<tr>
    <td><s:textfield name="name"/></td>
    <td><s:hidden name="historyId"/></td>
    <td><s:hidden name="status"  value="Available"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Could anyone please tell me what is the mistake I am doing here?

** Data is being updated successfully. But when i tried to add new information, I am unable to add the information.

Comment: are you sure the else code block is executed ?

Comment: Changing the code with equals(), the else block is executed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
if (name[i].length()>0  && (status[i] == "Available")))
```

to:

```
if (name[i].length()>0  && (status[i].equals("Available")))
```

and read this:

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Changing the code with equals() solved the problem. But the problem is that the available part is OK to update + add new items. I am facing problem for the other table. I used the same code and the only difference is I put "NA" instead of "Available".